# How to Find the Magnitude of Force and Direction

Tags: statics, homework

Give me some tips on how I can find the magnitude of $F_3$. The hint maybe is the angle of inclination of w axis such that the force components are equal along that axis, my instructor once told me. However, I can't still figure it out on how to solve for that angle.

The problem stated that $F_1$ is resolved in u and v axis, $F_2$ is resolved in v and w axis, while the $F_3$ is resolved in w and u axis. It is also stated in the problem that the components of $F_1$ and $F_2$ are equal along the v axis, the components of $F_2$ and $F_3$ are equal along the w axis, and the components of $F_1$ and $F_3$ are equal along the u axis.

[Original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0JRF.jpg)[image]

Comment: Can you include the original problem statement? Getting it 'second hand' risks translation errors

Comment: Hello, I already edit my entry. The original problem is now included in an image form.

Comment: Please keep the figure in the text of the problem (not as an external link).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming equilibrium, $\vec{F_1} + \vec{F_2} + \vec{F_3} = 0$ .
We have:
$$\vec{F_1} = \vec{{F_1}_u} + \vec{{F_1}_v}$$
$$\vec{F_2} = \vec{{F_2}_v} + \vec{{F_2}_w}$$
$$\vec{F_3} = \vec{{F_3}_w} + \vec{{F_3}_u}$$
And the problem states that:
$$\color{red}{\vec{{F_1}_v}} = \color{red}{\vec{{F_2}_v}}$$
$$\color{blue}{\vec{{F_2}_w}} = \color{blue}{\vec{{F_3}_w}}$$
$$\color{green}{\vec{{F_3}_u}} = \color{green}{\vec{{F_1}_u}}$$
So we can rewrite the equilibrium condition as:
$$\color{green}{\vec{{F_1}_u}} + \color{red}{\vec{{F_1}_v}} 
+ \color{red}{\vec{{F_2}_v}} + \color{blue}{\vec{{F_2}_w}} 
+ \color{blue}{\vec{{F_3}_w}} + \color{green}{\vec{{F_3}_u}} 
= 0$$
Or:
$$\color{green}{\vec{{F_1}_u}} + \color{red}{\vec{{F_1}_v}} + \color{blue}{\vec{{F_2}_w}} = 0$$
Which leads to:
$$\vec{{F_2}_w} = - \vec{F_1}$$
The rest of the solution is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: Can I assume that those forces are in equilibrium even though it is not stated in the original problem?

Comment: @Aiden That is an important question. If the forces are *not* in equilibrium then their resultant will *not* be zero, and the above solution will change. Unless we know the resultant vector (call it $\vec{F_R}$) , we won't have enough information to solve the problem because our calculations will end in $\vec{{F_2}_w} = \vec{F_R} - \vec{F_1}$ . With both $\vec{{F_2}_w}$ and $\vec{F_R}$ unknown, this equation will have infinitely many answers.

Answer (score 0):

The forces are lying on planes defined by the space grid system, u, v & w.  You need to work out the given angle between F2 and V-axis first, then from the given condition F1v = F2v, the angle between F1 and V-axis can be found. After that, everything is cleared up then.

[image]